# 2 localhosts on same computer

Tags: visual-studio, apache, localhost, wamp, webmatrix

Ok, so, I'm having some problems because I was using WAMP Server as localhost, then a friend of mine told me about Microsoft's VS for Web Developers.

Then, I started using Microsoft Webmatrix as my localhost and I uninstalled WAMP. But I started having some problems with the Webmatrix MySQL that I couldn't fix, and I had the idea of having 2 localhosts on the same computer: Microsoft WebMatrix for using ASP.NET and C# and WAMP for PHP and MySQL, but I can't use both at the same time.

Is it possible to change one of the localhost's address, for example, change `localhost` to `localhost2` on WAMP or on WebMatrix?

Comment: Consider to install on your system a virtualization solution as [Oracle VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [VMware Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/overview.html). In this way you can keep two isolated development environments on your PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to configure either WAMP or WebMatrix to use a separate port, which will allow you to use `localhost` for both, but one on port 80, and the other on some other port.

Comment: Ok, but where do I change wamp's port?

Answer (score 2):

It is, if you edit the systems "host"-file (as far as I remember it is somewhere below `\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` on windows). However, your problem is that you a wrong idea of what "localhost" means: As far as I can see you think "localhost" is a service, but in fact it is a feature from your tcp/ip-stack and defines a loopback-adress to your own machine. You should simply change the port of one of both services and then call it like `localhost:81`.